# Products add to cart button alignment

Tags: cart, magento2.3.5-p2

I have an issue i cant seem to find a setting for in the admin panel.

On the products page everything looks good except the add to cart button ( displayed in dutch ) is not aligned.

Is there a way i can get this aligned for a more clean view i am not way too familiar with the magento 2 but want to get it right :)
( i added the screenshot too )

Thanks in advance[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to align these buttons, you can use Javascript inside your Phtml files.

You need to calculate the outerHeight() for each row (in your case one row contains 5 products), and figure out the difference to the highest element in the row. Then, simply add the difference to the heighest element to all other elements, maybe use `margin-top` to the button or to the container of the button to achieve it.

You should read through the documentation to understand how you can adapt Magento2 Theme Files properly here:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/theme-best-practice.html

Once you identified your template you want to edit, you can add your script either directly inside the Phtml File, or better - create a new JS, register it for specific pages like [PLPs](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=what%20does%20PLP%20mean%20ecommerce) and add your JS file to these.

Otherwise, you can inject JS directly in the Phtml file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function (jQuery) {
            // .. add your JS here.. 
        });
</script>
```

The JS will be executed AFTER everything of the DOM has been loaded.